# can a dedicated GPU share to multiple kubernetes pods?

Tags: kubernetes, gpu

Is there a way we can share the GPU between multiple pods or we need some specific model of NVIDIA GPUS?

Comment: Short answer, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

> Short answer, yes :)

Long answer below :)

There is no "built-in" solution to achieve that, but you can use many tools (plugins) to control GPU. First look at the [Kubernetes official site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#v1-8-onwards):

> Kubernetes includes  **experimental**  support for managing AMD and NVIDIA GPUs (graphical processing units) across several nodes.
>
> This page describes how users can consume GPUs across different Kubernetes versions and the current limitations.

Look also about limitations:

> - GPUs are only supposed to be specified in the  `limits`  section, which means:
>   -   You can specify GPU  `limits`  without specifying  `requests`  because Kubernetes will use the limit as the request value by default.
>   -   You can specify GPU in both  `limits`  and  `requests`  but these two values must be equal.
>   -   You cannot specify GPU  `requests`  without specifying  `limits`.
> - Containers (and Pods) do not share GPUs. There's no overcommitting of GPUs.
> - Each container can request one or more GPUs. It is not possible to request a fraction of a GPU.

As you can see this supports GPUs between several nodes.  You can find the [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/#deploying-nvidia-gpu-device-plugin) how to deploy it.

Additionally, if you don't specify this in resource / request limits, the **containers** from all pods will have full access to the GPU as if they were normal processes. There is no need to do anything in this case.

For more look also at [this github topic](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52757).

Comment: so all pods have full access to 1 gpu ? Also what's the easy way to achieve and what kubernet version and method support this.